# Required permissions cannot be acquired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS7 Failed to grant minimum permission requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846816/iis7-failed-to-grant-minimum-permission-requests)

I'm developing an ASP.NET WebSite and I get an exception:

`Required permissions cannot be acquired.`

Is there a way to find out which permission(s) are missing?

I know the assembly that causes the exception, but I don't know which permission it requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

permcalc -sandbox

stores the information to an xml file that can be used in the web.config file.

Comment: This looks like a cool tool, although when I ran it on the openauth dll ( http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ ) it exited while generating output with the message "An error has occurred: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." :(

Answer (score 3):

[IIS7 Failed to grant minimum permission requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846816/iis7-failed-to-grant-minimum-permission-requests)

Answer (score 2):

In general this exception happens because your assembly is requesting permissions that IIS cannot grant.