# IIS7 Failed to grant minimum permission requests

Tags: iis, permissions

I get this error when I'm using FileHelpers.dll, but my IIS is set to Full trust level so it should not be that way

That's the full stack trace:

```
    [PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]
       System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +10238142
       System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +97

    [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FileHelpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
       System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
       System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +416
       System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +166
       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +190

    [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'FileHelpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11207304
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +388
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +232
       System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +48
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +210
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) +76
       System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +283
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +676

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'FileHelpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +76
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +1012
       System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +1025

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'FileHelpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11301302
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4338644
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I rebuilt my dev machine with a clean Windows 7 install.  After hunting around I discovered a solution that worked for me.

In your IIS application pool advanced settings, under "Process Model", set Load User Profile to true.

There are some other things to check like your trust level, but none of them applied to me (it was all full trust already on my dev machine).  Setting the application pool to load user profile fixed it.

Comment: where is this Process Model located ?

Comment: Start/Run inetmgr.  Look in Application Pools.  Right click your application pool.  Select Advanced Settings.  There it is

Answer (score 23):

I've seen this error in another instance where, for example, IIS is running an application or virtual path via a UNC path (i.e. `\\svr\share\folder`).  Even if `Load User Profile=true` I still got the PolicyException error.  It was solved by running the [Code Access Security Policy Tool (Caspol.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/caspol-exe-code-access-security-policy-tool) to add full trust to the UNC path.  Since we had both `64 bit` and `32 bit` of `.Net 2.x` and `.Net 4.x`, I ran it in all four environments as follows:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\svr\share\folder\*"   FullTrust -exclusive on
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\svr\share\folder\*"   FullTrust -exclusive on
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\svr\share\folder\*"   FullTrust -exclusive on
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\svr\share\folder\*"   FullTrust -exclusive on
```

Some notes of caution:

- For `.Net 4.x` be sure to enable the [NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/netfx40-legacysecuritypolicy-element) to `true` or the `caspol.exe` commands won't work as expected.
- Do **not** add duplicate entries with `caspol.exe` for a given environment. Run the commands below to view your entries:

  `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -a -lg`
  `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -a -lg`
  `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\caspol.exe -a -lg`
  `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\caspol.exe -a -lg`

Answer (score 4):

This is a security/trust issue. Open the properties of the DLL in Windows Explorer. It's likely marked as blocked because it was downloaded it from the internet. Go to properties & click the "unblock" button and the problem may be solved.

[image]

Comment: in my case it happened exactly because of this. thanks!

Comment: You saved my life, this worked for me ... VS 2019 Community Edition - Thank you !!!

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue with Windows 2008 R2 where our application would work fine in 64bit mode but when switched to 32 bit mode would cease to function and throw the permission error, turns out, in IIS7 under Advanced Settings >> Process Model >> the "Identity" setting had been switched to "Application Pool Identity" by default and may need changed to "Network Service" to work in 32 bit mode.

We did that and now we are humming along smoothly. Figured this tidbit of info may be the reason that everyone points to folder permissions, because technically it is a folder permission issue. But the change was in IIS and not the security settings on the folders themselves.

Comment: same thing worked for me as described by Samuel...... Just to add one thing this is the Application pool's Advance setting....

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is something of a generic Assembly will not load error. I appreciate all of the other posts since they became a list of possible sources of the error.

I found one more. I had tried all of the above with no success. I finally realized I was publishing the Web Application from Visual Studios Express 2008 with a Build Configuration of 'Debug'. After changing the Build Configuration to 'Release', the Web App worked.

Specifics: 
Visual Studios Express 2008 moving files to IIS7.5 on Win 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, I solved the issue with following steps:

1. Go to IIS.
2. Right click on the website folder and see it's app pool.
3. Right click on the app pool and go to advanced settings.
4. In the process model section set `load user profile` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

the problem her is belong to use ddl not trust for the SharePoint 
to solve the problem :

1. open the IIS
2. click on .net truest levels
3. chose full(internal)

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but my answer was deleted because i have only posted a link.

maybe you will get this error:
ERROR:

Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’ or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)

This error occurs because the default trust level for local machine is Full trust, but in the network share not.

So to compile your applications remotely you have to:
Go to Control Panel ->Adiministrative Tools->Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration
Open My Computer->Runtime Security Policy ->Machine >Code Groups >All Code>New (right click to appear the menu to select New
)

The URL field in the next figure is the path to the shared folder , in this case, but you can choose Strong Names( for .exe or .dll) etc

Click Finish and you can compile your app!!

https://medium.com/@marcoscavaleiro/failed-to-grant-minimum-permission-requests-7245cf694ebd

Answer (score -2):

In your IIS 6.0 application pool advanced settings, under "Process Model", set Load User Profile to true.

There are some other things to check like your trust level, but none of them applied to me (it was all full trust already on my dev machine). Setting the application pool to load user profile fixed it.

that help to solve

required permissions cannot be acquired in iis  to solve it..