# Could not load file or assembly 'volmodelexcel.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, excel, dll

I am having a problem with this .dll file. I have tried using Dependency Walker and it tells me: "Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module." with red flags on SHLWAPI.DLL and MPR.DLL. 
When I run my C# program I get: "Could not load file or assembly 'volmodelexcel.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." There is also a excel spreadsheet and instructions to set it up. The error occurs on step 2: 2. Manually register the dll, "regasm /codebase somelocation/volmodel/bin/volmodelexcel.dll" This gives me:

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.3053
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'volmodelexcel, Version=
1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53504c71e2f5ab54' or one of its depende
ncies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8
0131417)

What can be done to find the problem.

Comment: Provide it a valid dll with those unresolved imports fixed.

Comment: All of the .dll files exist and are fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846816/iis7-failed-to-grant-minimum-permission-requests -- which also has an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Just to add additional info for the previous answer (which solve the problem in our case). In addition, you need to run VS 2005 as Admin. Sometimes, you will not get the UAC Prompt, so in this case, goto Control Panel, Action Center, Change User Access Control, and set it to "Notify me when programs tries to make changes to my computer" (2nd choice from the bottom).

Even when you try to modify the .NET Configuration for Zone Trust Level, under Windows 7, you should see the UAC Prompt. If you don't see this prompt, then admin is not active.

It took us 5 days to find out why the errors are not cleared from VS 2005 under Windows 7 64 bit. But now, it is OK.